# xcode 4 - custom keyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode4, keyboard, textfield

Is there a way to stop the default keyboard and have my custom designed keyboard when user clicks on TextField ?

I already designed my buttons to be always available similar to a calculator. It has numbers from 0 to 9 , decimal dot and backspace.

Comment: Is there an example code??. The buttons are UIButtons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with iOS 3.2, you can attach any `UIView` to your `UITextField` to be used as a keyboard:

```
myTextField.inputView = myFakeKeyboard;
```

You can also attach a toolbar above the keyboard (system or custom one) :

```
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = myToolbar;
```

By the way, if you need a numeric pad with 0-9, the decimal dot, and Backspace, you can use the `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` type for your UITextField. But this one is only available starting from iOS 4.1, and you have to be aware that some locales use a comma instead of a dot as a decimal separator, and this keyboard type shows a comma or a dot regarding of the current locale of the device it's running on.

Comment: is there a way to have a custom color to the default keyboard?

Comment: Let's say you have designed your "fake keyboard" in a XIB along your UITextField. Both of them are "wired" via `IBOutlet`s. In your class’ `viewDidLoad` method, both outlets are loaded and ready to use, so you can "plug" your keyboard there.

Comment: And no, by definition the *default* keyboard is not meant to be customized.

Comment: Yes I understand. But you wrote "myFakeKeyboard" , which is a group of buttons so how could I have them as "myKeybaord" grouped

Comment: All your custom buttons, you put them in a UIView the same size as the default keyboard, and *this* UIView (named `myFakeKeyboard`) becomes the `inputView` of your text field.

Comment: sorry but still no luck there. added my view there add could not launch the customized keyboard. the default keyboard still there.

Comment: sorry but still no luck there. added my view there and could not launch the customized keyboard. the default keyboard still there

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in your viewController and its enough :)

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     return NO; //hide keyboard
}
```