# How to Show TableView instead of keyboard while editing in a TextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I want a Table view to appear while editing in a Text Field instead of keyboard.

How would I populate this table view with data?

Comment: How do you propose to enter data into the text field without a keyboard?

Comment: i don't. i want that textfield to be filled with data from one of the tableview row

Comment: use a button instead.... that will be much easier for u.

Comment: There are a lot of answers about this already. Hiding the keyboard involves setting the inputView of the text field to the new table view. You populate the tableview in its delegate.

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 4 - custom keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451912/xcode-4-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit weird, but you could implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`, and use it to show your table view, then return `NO` to suppress the keyboard display.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Wain said, Or if you don't wanna go with textfield delegates then you can put a transparent button over your `textfield`, and on tap of button you can show  the tableView.